# Cannot reach second flask server from external ip address through apache/httpd

Tags: python, apache, flask, networking, centos

I am currently working on a second api on an already running server which serves

port 80,

and other virtualhosts connected to flasks for each api port

via apache/httpd on Centos 7.

api1 is running with wsgi
api2 currently on plain flask webserver for testing

**Problem** is now that I can reach api2 on localhost:api2_port, but not on its external ip adress

I tried mtr from another network which actually logs returning packages from api2 external_ip:api2_port.

There is a hardware firewall between them, which is not under my control, however I was told, that the ports were opened as I asked. I think the mtr output also confirms this.

**Questions**
Does anyone have an idea how I can debug this?

Is there maybe a problem with multiple flask instances running on the server?

=> This however should've been covered by the localhost:api2_port test

The Virtualhost config is plain basic and works for api1

```
<VirtualHost *:api2_port>
    ServerName external_ip:api2_port
    ServerAlias Projectname
    DocumentRoot /var/www/projectname
</VirtualHost>
```

Thanks in advance for any suggestion

Edit 1:

Also

the project files and folders are owned by a non-root user who also runs api1

iptables has rules for tcp input and output for the api ports

selinux is disabled

I am currently out of ideas

Comment: if you defined server with address `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` then it can't be accessed from external computer - only local program can access it. You would have to use `0.0.0.` (or IP one of your local network cards) to get access from external computers.

Comment: Thanks for the response. The server was already running on 0.0.0.0 .
I found out, that it was a firewall issue after all

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for reading and responses.

The Problem was a missing firewall rule after all, so it is solved.